# get parent name of button in FlyoutControl

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, flyout

I have a flyoutControl that contains stackPanel and button. I need flyoutControl's name after btnC clicked (get flyoutControl's name from sender)

```
<dxe:FlyoutControl x:Name="flcA">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button x:Name="btnB"/>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button x:Name="btnC" Click="btnC_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</dxe:FlyoutControl>
```

Comment: Can't you simply use flyoutControl.Parent.Name?

Comment: @JonasMetzler No. I have ten flyout that every flyout has a button and click event. I need one function for all ten flyout and in function close the same flyout.

Comment: Assuming that you want to close several **FlyoutControls** at the same time, I guess you can bind ``IsOpen`` of all  your **FlyoutControls** to a single boolean property and just switch it there.

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding Thanks. I bind flyoutcontrol to button tag and use for close it